# basic of Jordan Form proof

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

while studying matrix calculus, I face this problem from "Matrix Methods an Introduction". I think this problem from 5.4 of this book gives a good understanding of "Jordan Forms". So I'll be grateful helping me solving it.

> Show that if λ is an eigenvalue of A, then it is also an eigenvalue
> for $S^{-1}AS$ for any nonsingular matrix S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\ v\ $ is an eigenvector of $\ A\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ \lambda\ $, what happens when you multiply $\ S^{-1}v\ $ on the left by $\ S^{-1}AS\ $?

Comment: v is e.vector => $Av = \lambda v$.  and $$(S^{-1}AS) S^{-1}v = S^{-1}Av = S^{-1} \lambda v = \lambda S^{-1}v$$ . so $ \lambda $ is eigenvalue and $S^{-1}v$ is eigenvector for $S^{-1}AS$ . Thank you sir.